# One-To-One One-To-Many relation

Tags: nhibernate

two entities's mapping files as follow,I want to build ont-to-many relation for two entities but the "one" entity's column is not the key column.Because of the DB table could not change, Could I have a method to build it.Please help me,thx.

```
<class name ="Sue" table="[Sue]">
    <id name="ID" column ="ID" type="Guid" />

    <property name="SueSmallType">
        <column name="SueSmallType" sql-type ="nvarchar(Max)" />
    </property>

</class>


<class name ="SueType" table="[SueType]">
    <id name="ID" column ="ID" type="Guid" />

    <property name="Code">
        <column name="Code" sql-type ="nvarchar(Max)" />
    </property>

</class>
```

for example build the relation to "SueSmallType" and "Code",what should I do.

Answer (score 1):

property-ref is there for this scenario, but you'll loose lazyloading because "SueSmallType" is not the Id of the referenced object.

```
<class name ="Sue" table="[Sue]">
    <id name="ID" column ="ID" type="Guid" />

    <many-to-one name="SueType" column="SueSmallType" property-ref="Code"/>
</class>

<class name ="SueType" table="[SueType]">
    <id name="ID" column ="ID" type="Guid" />

    <property name="Code">
        <column name="Code" length="8000" />
    </property>
</class>
```

note the length property over a certan threshold (8000 for example) has the same effect as setting the sqltype to the databases long text type (nvarchar(max), text)